# Best strategy for caching GraphQL content with permissions and authorization

Tags: caching, server, graphql

I am building a service using a GraphQL server.
It has sessions and user permissions as any other usual services.
For example, `{ viewer { friends { name } } }` will look different for each user session.

What is the best strategy for caching such GraphQL query results?
Also, note that since this is GraphQL, each query may look slightly different. For example, some user may want `{ viewer { friends { id name } } }` with `id` being the additional field.

Is there any hosted caching solutions for GraphQL?
Can anyone using GraphQL in production share their insights?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/6q7ern/django_cached_page_generate_cache_key_for/?st=j634d554&sh=d28066e0 They are caching the query done on the graphql view. They may be able to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're runing `graphql` on javascript, you can use Facebook's powerfull utility `Dataloader` 
https://github.com/facebook/dataloader

It can cache and batch your queries.

As for the caching session queries, `DataLoader` is also able to do that. 
You only have to create a new dataloader per request. More info can be found here
https://github.com/facebook/dataloader#creating-a-new-dataloader-per-request

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I am already using dataloader, but it still runs on my own graphql server and hence add loads on my server. What I am looking for is a cache layer that is external to my graphql server, not internal.